# Position li elements in jQuery simplyScroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, simplyscroll

I can't seem to work out how to position the elements so that they are different distances from the left.

Its been a while since I used jQuery and I cannot seem to find an answer.

[Here](http://www.stredtech.co.uk/YMD/) is what I currently have

Using margin and padding does not move the elements.

**Note:** currently I am working on the IE 8 or below version of the CSS the main css does not contain all the classes and IDs

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want random left margin for those circles right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just needed to add position relative then I could use the padding!

The simple things are the worst!

Answer (score 0):

The padding must use it in the CSS:

```
.feedback {
    padding: 10 px;
}
```

Comment: It is in the IE css, that is the one that I have been working on. setting the padding like that has no effect, it would also change them all, I want to target each li element individually

Answer (score 0):

You also need to include display: inline-block; for the ul and/or the li elements depending on what you are trying to achieve.